# Fix APIs connection problem with old Android OS (Android 7 or less) in React Native using axios

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I used 'axios' library to fetch the data. It is working perfect on new Android devices (Android 9 & 10) but on old devices (Android 7 or less) it always gives Network Error like this: [ Error: Network Error] it seems like the devices could not establish a connection with the https URL.

Comment: Hi there I also got this issue. I hope this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69536652/11105888

Answer (score 0):

**Solution-1:**

Try adding bellow code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Solution-2:**

Problem with http and https request. SO to enable https request try the one below :

The easy way to implement this is to use this attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml where you allow all http for all requests:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: I am already try this two solutions.