# Apis are not working on old Android devices (Android 7 or less) in React Native using axios but working in new devices

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, axios

I used 'axios' library to fetch the data. It is working perfect on new Android devices (Android 9 & 10) but on old devices (Android 7 or less) it always gives Network Error like this: [ Error: Network Error] it seems like the devices could not establish a connection with the https URL.

This question is duplicate of this link below I am also getting this error can anyone help out.

[Fix APIs connection problem with old Android OS (Android 7 or less) in React Native using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69389381/11105888)

```js
const SERVER_URL = 'https://*****.com/****';

export const getCities = () => async dispatch => {
  let res = await axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/GetCityList`);
  res = parser.parse(res.data).ArrayOfMCity.mCity;
  if (res && !res.length) {
    res = [res];
  }
  const dropdownCities = [];
  res.forEach(r => {
    dropdownCities.push({label: r.CityName, value: r.CityID});
  });
  dispatch({
    type: GET_CITY,
    payload: {
      cities: res ? res : [],
      dropdownCities,
    },
  });
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, did you try the solutions on the link you shared? Make sure you rebuild the APK after - React native can get a bit funky so do it in Android Studio to make sure. We'd need to see your code and end point if these solutions don't work

Comment: Yeah I have tried the solution given in that link but it didn't worked. The thing is it is working perfectly in new android devices but not in old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got the solution I have tried other api other than my api and it is working perfectly. So I found out that I am having a certificate issue in android old devices. The certificate is not working in old devices from version 7.1 and older.

Here is the link which says that many websites will stop working in older android devices from 1st September 2021

https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/11/07/many-websites-will-stop-working-on-older-android-versions-in-2021/